# pandas.plotで凡例の場所を変更したい

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

pandas.plotを用いて株価のグラフを作成したのですが、凡例が変な位置に来てしまいます。

matplotlibであれば下記のように、`legend` に対して `loc` を指定してやれば位置を調整できると思うのですが、pandas.plotだと出来ないのでしょうか？
(matplotlibのラッパーなので、難しいことをすれば出来るのでしょうか？)

**matplotlibだと以下の書き方ができる**

```py
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0), loc='lower right', borderaxespad=1, fontsize=18)
```

**問題のプログラム**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

domesticdemand = {9009:'京成電鉄',1812:'鹿島建設',8331:'千葉銀行',8267:'イオン',9735:'セコム'}

plt.figure()
for i in domesticdemand:
    filepath = "./kabuka/" + str(i) + ".csv"
    kabukadata = pd.read_csv(filepath,index_col=[0],encoding="SHIFT-JIS")
    kabukadata['終値'].plot(label=domesticdemand[i], legend=True,figsize=(10,5))
plt.savefig('kabuka.png')
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[Set legend position when plotting a pandas dataframe with a second y-axis via pandas plotting interface duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54090983/9014308), [How to plot two pandas time series on same plot with legends and secondary y-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46011940/9014308), [Pandas bar plot with specific colors and legend location?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11348183/9014308)

Answer (score 2):

```py
kabukadata['終値'].plot(label=domesticdemand[i], legend=True,figsize=(10,5))
```

を次のように変更したら、うまくいきませんかね？

```py
kabukadata['終値'].plot(label=domesticdemand[i], figsize=(10,5)).legend(loc='lower right')
```

Comment: 無事できました！！　なぜお分かりになったのでしょうか。

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: ↑公式にも載っていません。。

Comment: 適当にググっただけです。どんなキーワードだったか、どのページを見たのかは...忘れました。すいません、明確な回答ではなくて。